# Tengo un problema con una consulta en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada recintos que contiene:

| id | parroquia_id | nombre_recinto | num_juntas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | Escuela general | 6 |

y una tabla llamada veedores que contiene 6 registros como este en ese mismo recinto:

| id | dni | user_id | recinto__id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2345666632 | 14 | 3 |

Sin embargo necesito sumar el numero de juntas y contar cuantas personas se encuentran registradas en ese recinto por lo que tengo una consulta:

```
select  SUM(r.num_juntas) as total_juntas,
COUNT(v.id) as total_veed,
p.nombre_parroquia
from recintos as r
left join parroquias as p on
p.id = r.parroquia_id
left join cantones as c on
c.id = p.canton_id
left join veedores as v on
v.recinto__id = r.id
group by p.id;
```

Pero el problema es que el resultado me devuelve:

num_juntas: 36

total_veed: 6

Es decir que el "num_juntas" se suma el numero de veces que tiene en el "total_veed"
Como puedo evitar eso?
el resultado que debería esperar es:

num_juntas: 6

total_veed: 6

Comment: Puedes hacer una subconsulta en el select del numero de juntas

Comment: Me podrías indicar como realizarla? o alguna pauta?

Comment: Realice la subconsulta quedó de esta manera:
select  
(select SUM(r.num_juntas) as total_juntas
from recintos as r
left join parroquias as p on
p.id = r.parroquia_id
group by p.id) as total_juntas,
COUNT(v.id) as total_veed,
p.nombre_parroquia
from recintos as r
left join parroquias as p on
p.id = r.parroquia_id
left join cantones as c on
c.id = p.canton_id
left join veedores as v on
v.recinto__id = r.id
group by p.id;

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
Claro que si pongo un where me arroja correctamente pero necesito retornar todos